# How to fight deep creases/intersecting mesh when sculpting?

Tags: sculpting

Often, when sculpting, you are unintentionally creating deep creases with mesh hided inside of your model. Here are some screenshots of a quick example.

[image: Mesh]
[image: Wire]

In the real world it can happen when you model bended limbs or hair locks, or when joining 2 meshes together.

So the question is if there is a quick or "right" way to fix a situation like this? Because smoothing it "till nothing left" is not an option...

Comment: I usually just use an excess of the smooth brush at high strengths in such cases, and it works for me. Why is smooth not an  option?

Comment: Because in a particular case you will smooth the whole model until you get rid of the unwanted mesh, in case of joining 2 meshes sometimes you will never smooth it enough. For example how do you add a high poly ear to a high poly dyntopo sculpted head? Like you have some creature with lots of geometry, then you want to add a human ear and then to change the ear with sculpting. How do you do it so you can have seamless mesh?

Comment: I'd connect them with a boolean modifier or remesh, the go over the seam with a simplify brush and a smooth brush.

Comment: Shrinkwrap would work also. But with all of these, if you're working on detailed model you might have to detach the part that needs work and re-attach it later. Or you could just go into edit mode and do it manually. But as far as a "right" way, as far as I know there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

The only tool that worked for me in a similar situation was the flatten tool. I had to run it over for a long time and it did make a bit of a mess. It was almost as it kept digging the crease slowly out. The resulting mess was not hard to clean up and it got rid of the sharp crease between two joined objects, that no other option worked. I had originally the same problem, that if I used the draw brush or even the clay strips brush to build the crease up as soon as I tried to use smooth brush right after it would make the crease come right back.